# How do I setup a custom host in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, hosts

I want to redirect a host to local machine, in windows you get a hosts file. Is there something like this in Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts*** on windows and ***/etc/hosts*** on linux(unix,bsd) are more or less the same thing.

Comment: tried adding an entry there, and then pinged it - its not pinging local IP, but some internet address with the same name

Comment: /etc/host.conf: line 5: bad command `192.168.1.4 mintbox.com'

Comment: The file is /etc/hosts not /etc/hosts.conf